# Arithmetic operations in regex

Tags: regular-expression, python, gedit

I am using gedit regex plugin (Python style regex). I would like to do some arithmetic operation on a backreference to a group.

For example:

```
PART 1 DATA MODELS Chapter  
2 Entity-Relationship Model 27
```

I would like to change it to be

```
PART 1 DATA MODELS Chapter  25
2 Entity-Relationship Model 27
```

My regex is `^(PART.*)\n(.*\s(\d+))\n`, and I would like to replace it with `\1 \3-2\n\2\n`. But the replacing regex is not right.

Comment: See the [Python `re` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for the syntax of the regular expressions. The [replacement text syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) is also documented there; the only escapes there are to call up a group from the input.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks! I took a look at the links, but still cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I don't now about gedit, but in `vim` Arithmetic operations in regex are easy.  for example:

```
:%s/\d\+/\=submatch(0)+25/g
```

finds every integer and adds 25 to it.

Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245087/math-operations-in-regex) a Perl solution to a similar problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, so I answered the question in your title.

Comment: And `emacs`. Both it and `vim` are mentioned in this [SuperUser Q/A](http://superuser.com/questions/193345/any-text-editor-that-can-apply-some-math-to-replacement-text) ... For `emacs` it is: `\.` in the replacement param, followed by a lisp expression using the backrefernces...

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that you want to add at the end of each line beginning by `'PART'` the last number of the next line minus 2.  If so, it can be done with `'awk'`:

```
awk '!/^PART/{print}/^PART/{
getline next_line;
match(next_line, "[^ ]*$");
print $0 " " substr(next_line, RSTART) - 2;
print next_line}' <your file>
```

This script runs under the assumption that the last line of the input file will not begin by `'PART'`, and that the line following a line beginning by `'PART'` will contain a space and a number at its end.  If needed, error checking could be added.